# Balanced and unbalanced short circuit voltage of transformer

Tags: transformer, three-phase

This might be trivial, but I'd like some hint on where to start.

I'm calculating power flow for three-phase-four-wire distribution networks. Positive sequence and zero sequence short circuit voltages of transformers are given. For example:

[image]

But to build one-line equivalent (balanced) model, I need short circuit voltage (in %) and its real component (in %). I am wondering how to convert such parameters.

Other parameters, like iron loss, are the same for balanced and unbalanced model, I presume. The Python package I used is `pandapower`. Here is the documentation for transformer:

https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/stable/elements/trafo.html#pandapower.create_transformer_from_parameters

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by *short circuit voltage* - it will depend entirely on the supply's impedance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found some equation in `pandapower` documentation, saying short-circuit impedance can be calculated from short circuit voltage and rated apparent power.

Comment: It seems that you don't know what it means and neither do I. Panda website is pretty useless in help from what I can tell.

Comment: I have no clue, in deed. Just uploaded a picture for what I have right now. Hope it's more clear.